# Code Highlighting for Joomla

Tags: joomla, syntax-highlighting

I need syntax highlighting of source code from various languages (PHP, C#, VB, etc) within articles I have in Joomla. I have tried enabling the Geshi plugin, updating the language files and putting the code into my Joomla article - however I can't seem to get it to work.

I have also tried CodeCitation from JED but again, the problem seems to be the same - I don't know how to tell Joomla to process it as code. I placed {codecitation} and {/codecitation} around my code (as well as including the brush value) but it doesn't work. I am unsure if these tags should be placed on the source or the wysiwug

Could someone please assist with an alternative method or work out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CodeCitation: if you already wrote the article using the tags (i.e. `{codecitation} code {/codecitation}`), it should work. Did you check if you enable the mambot?

Comment: I have some problems making it work, but in the end it did. +1. Problems I still have: it loses indentation, there is no toolbar as stated in the download page (which would be nice if you cited in your answer to make it better for reference). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As of Joomla 3.4 Geshi has been removed - but you can still get [Geshi+](http://www.geoffhayward.eu/blog/the-secret-of-joomla-s-geshi-syntax-highlighter) (geshi repackaged with all the additional languages) - & see the tips [here](http://dotcomxl.com/index.php/tutorials/web-design/115-joomla-syntax-highlighter) on how to configure geshi.

An example of Geshi+ working is [here](http://it-offshore.co.uk/linux).

There are now Joomla plugins using [highlightjs](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/authoring-a-content/cedhighlightjs) & [google's prettify library](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/authoring-a-content/cedprettify) to highlight syntax but I found geshi+ worked much better

Comment: You can also get the latest Code highlighter (Geshi )for Joomla here http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/script-code-highlighter .

Comment: Thanks for this. Geshi+ seems to work fine on Joomla 3.7.0, too.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain if you can use it in Joomla or not. I use the syntax highlighter by Alex Gorbatchev. I have used it in a couple of blogs (wordpress for instance) and in some stand alone web pages. Not hard to intergrate. It uses the 'pre' tags. You need to be sure the code is already escaped. It may be worth a look. Here is a link.

http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

Hope this helps.

Bob